# How to use catkin to cross compile and ignore python

Tags: robotic-arm, python, catkin, cross-compiling

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm working on cross compiling to an ARM platform that doesn't have python.

Is there a way to specify catkin to ignore all catkin_python_setup() calls?

As well it can't find the PythonInterp and I guess I can set that through the environment variable for my host machine, but the target won't have python.

I'm hoping to be able to compile ros packages that contain python nodes and dependencies on rospy but functionally ignore them through the process, even if they tag along and are present in the installed files for now.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/96966/how-to-use-catkin-to-cross-compile-and-ignore-python/) by [Chad Rockey](https://answers.ros.org/users/29/chad-rockey/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4541 on 2013-11-01

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not that I am aware of.

You could override the `catkin_python_setup` macro with an empty version in your CMake toolchain file. But that might not work depending on the order of of evaluation in CMake, which I'm not sure about. In which case you would just need to fork catkin and disable that macro.

If you want a CMake option to do that then I would open a pull request against catkin.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2013-11-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2